# uint16[] memory tokenIds = new uint16[](0) what this mean?

Tags: solidity

`uint16[] memory tokenIds  = new uint16[](0)`
is this mean a uint16[] array length =0?  What's the point？

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you're created a new dynamic memory array called `_tokenIds` which its length 0.

Comment: thank you!  I just think it's fixed size